# Decorate eloquent model attribute - Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an eloquent model like this:

```
<?php

 namespace News\Model;

 class News extends Model
 {
    public $fillable = [
      'title',
      'desc'
    ];

    public function getUpperTitle(){
         return strtoupper($this->title);      
    }

  }
```

and have controller like this:

```
use News;
class NewsController extends Controller
{

      public function index()
      {
            return News::all();
      }
}
```

Now I want to return all news with uppercase of title (title Decorated) without call `getUpperTitle()` and just use eloquent function.

Result that I want:

```
[
  {
    "title":"NEWS 1",
    "desc":"News Description1"
  },
  {
    "title":"NEWS 2",
    "desc":"News Description2"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an accessor in your Model class:

```
public function getTitleAttribute($value)
{
    return strtoupper($value);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor